# CSS - resize both and overflow hidden properties aren't working with position absolute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a small project and it's to practice drag and drop with HTML and JS, I have 4 divs in a container 'x' (with images in them) and another container 'y' to drag and drop those divs to that container 'y', but if I drag them all there, the first div just sets to the top left corner and the rest under them (or beside each other if I set their display to inline-block). So, I want to make those divs movable on that container 'y' which I dragged into to move them around wherever I need. The divs are resizable with resize: auto and overflow: hidden (I tried with hidden, auto and visible and all are the same, not working).

To get the drag and move function, I used [this](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_draggable.asp) tutorial from W3schools, I made 4 functions for all the divs, everything's the same, except the ID's and the function names which are different. Now, this function breaks the resize feature because I give the divs a position: absolute to make them movable, and it's that line of CSS and some help of JS which breaks that feature. I wrote some of the main codes below:

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
    ev.dataTransfer.dropEffect = "move";
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}


var drag1 = document.getElementById("drag1");
var drag2 = document.getElementById("drag2");
var drag3 = document.getElementById("drag3");
var drag4 = document.getElementById("drag4");

dragElement1(drag1);
dragElement2(drag2);
dragElement3(drag3);
dragElement4(drag4);

function dragElement1(elmnt) {
    var pos1 = 0, pos2 = 0, pos3 = 0, pos4 = 0;
    if (document.getElementById(elmnt.id)) {
        /* if present, the header is where you move the DIV from:*/
        document.getElementById(elmnt.id).onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    } else {
        /* otherwise, move the DIV from anywhere inside the DIV:*/
        elmnt.onmousedown = dragMouseDown;
    }

    function dragMouseDown(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // get the mouse cursor position at startup:
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        document.onmouseup = closeDragElement;
        // call a function whenever the cursor moves:
        document.onmousemove = elementDrag;
    }

    function elementDrag(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        e.preventDefault();
        // calculate the new cursor position:
        pos1 = pos3 - e.clientX;
        pos2 = pos4 - e.clientY;
        pos3 = e.clientX;
        pos4 = e.clientY;
        // set the element's new position:
        elmnt.style.top = (elmnt.offsetTop - pos2) + "px";
        elmnt.style.left = (elmnt.offsetLeft - pos1) + "px";
    }

    function closeDragElement() {
        /* stop moving when mouse button is released:*/
        document.onmouseup = null;
        document.onmousemove = null;
    }
} /* The other 3 functions are the same, only the ID's and the function names are different */
```

```css
#images-container .resize {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    max-width: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    max-height: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    resize: both !important;
    overflow: auto !important;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 4px;
} // The only piece of CSS which has the issue
```

```html
<div id="images-container" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
    <div class="resize" style="background: url('images/photo-1.jpg') center no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <!-- <img src="images/photo-1.jpg" alt="Image 1" > -->
    </div>
    <div class="resize" style="background: url('images/photo-2.jpg') center no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <!-- <img src="images/photo-2.jpg" alt="Image 2" > -->
    </div>
    <div class="resize" style="background: url('images/photo-3.jpg') center no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <!-- <img src="images/photo-3.jpg" alt="Image 3" > -->
    </div>
    <div class="resize" style="background: url('images/photo-4.jpg') center no-repeat; background-size: cover; background-position: center center;" id="drag4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
        <!-- <img src="images/photo-4.jpg" alt="Image 4" > -->
    </div>
</div>

        <div id="gallery" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
```

I want to know what causes this issue and what's the fix of it, is it an issue from JS or the CSS, or both? Though I suspect that it's from JS. I didn't and don't want to use jQuery for this.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add please a working example? Have you tried overflow hidden on your absolutely placed elements?

Comment: @RauliRajande I made a working example of it on Codepen: https://codepen.io/KourkenK/pen/ejBOMR
I know, the CSS is a bit bad, as I'm not concentrating on the style now. I tried hidden, auto and visible with the same results.

Comment: function "dragMouseDown(e)" line "e.preventDefault(); " doesn't let resizing to start.

Best solution would be to implement some kind of handle for resizing (or dragging) as these operations clash in principle with each other.

Comment: @RauliRajande Ok, thanks, I was thinking that it's coming from the functions, but not sure from which line. So, how can I make that handle?

Comment: Not sure how to do this. Both events ( drag/resize ) are triggered by `click` on the element. So they are both trying to happen in the same time. That's what's causing the problem. I can help you though with optimizing your existing code. First, you use 4 different functions `dragElement1,dragElement2....`. You could've just used one and call it 4 times with different attributes. For eg `dragElement(elem1); dragElement(elem2) etc` No need for a function for each. BUT BETTER SOLUTION would be to use only 1 func and call it only once. For that see here - [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ej9fqgsn/7/)

Comment: @MihaiT That's really cool, thanks man, I understood the code, I read about querySelectorAll() a few weeks ago, it's cool to know that it solves this issue of writing multiple functions into 1 function. The only thing to know now is how to make the resize and drag both work without any conflicts. Thanks again!